# Ceph - reset ceph osd_max_backfills to default value

Tags: ceph

I am attempting to reset some backfill settings to defaults after having changed them to slow down the backfilling. I am struggling to work out how to do it though:

This example shows that the backfill is still set to "override", and I would like it to be default?

```
$ ceph config show osd.11 | grep osd_max_backfills
osd_max_backfills                                1000                                                                     override
```

I have tried using

```
$ ceph config rm osd osd_max_backfills
```

Pretty sure these are the default values:

```
$ ceph-conf --show-config | egrep "osd_recovery_max_active|osd_recovery_op_priority|osd_max_backfills"  
osd_max_backfills = 1
osd_recovery_max_active = 0
osd_recovery_max_active_hdd = 3
osd_recovery_max_active_ssd = 10
osd_recovery_op_priority = 3
```

But no luck with this either. Any help would be appreciated on how to set and unset these values in v17x

Comment: In Ceph Quincy this is handled by [mclock scheduler](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/rados/configuration/mclock-config-ref/). You can also disable the mclock scheduler: https://www.clyso.com/blog/ceph-how-do-disable-mclock-scheduler/

Answer (score 0):

Read up about mclock -- by default the old throttles are bypassed now.